# How to correctly allocate memory and return a 2D array

Tags: arrays, c

I get runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int *'. This is my code:

```
int min (int a, int b){
    return a < b ? a : b;
}
int max (int a, int b){
    return a > b ? a : b;
}

int** intervalIntersection(
        int** firstList, int firstListSize, int* firstListColSize,
        int** secondList, int secondListSize, int* secondListColSize,
        int* returnSize, int** returnColumnSizes){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int **res;
    while (i < firstListSize && j < secondListSize) {
        int l = max(firstList[i][0], secondList[j][0]);
        int r = min(firstList[i][1], secondList[j][1]);
 
        if (l <= r){
            res[a][0] = l; - *I suspect error in this line*
            res[a][1] = r; - *and this also*
            a++;
        }
 
        if (firstList[i][1] < secondList[j][1])
            i++;
        else
            j++;
    }
    res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (a * 2));
    *returnSize = a;
    **returnColumnSizes = 2;
    return res;
}
```

```
runtime error: load of null pointer of type 'int *'
```

I need to return the intersection of these two interval lists as a 2D array. Also, I think I incorrectly malloc my new 2D array, so after that I got this error. I would appreciate it if someone could change the code so that after finding the intersection, the two points are added to the 2D array.

After the fixes @macjayz,
I get the heap-buffer-overflow error

```
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000258 at pc 0x564ab16e9fdc bp 0x7fff1adb4900 sp 0x7fff1adb48f0
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000258 thread T0
    #2 0x7f1568a4d0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
0x602000000258 is located 0 bytes to the right of 8-byte region [0x602000000250,0x602000000258)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f1569692bc8 in malloc (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.5+0x10dbc8)
    #3 0x7f1568a4d0b2 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c047fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c047fff8000: fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa
  0x0c047fff8010: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa
  0x0c047fff8020: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa
  0x0c047fff8030: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa
=>0x0c047fff8040: fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00 fa fa fa 00[fa]fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8050: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa
  0x0c047fff8060: fa fa fd fa fa fa fd fa fa fa 00 00 fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8070: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c047fff8090: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

Example:
firstList = [[0,2],[5,10],[13,23],[24,25]]

secondList = [[1,5],[8,12],[15,24],[25,26]]

Output: [[1,2],[5,5],[8,10],[15,23],[24,24],[25,25]]

Comment: You are assigning values to `res` before allocating it. You should allocate before the loop.

Comment: @EmanuelP I don't know how much memory I need to allocate but even if I choose a random number I get another error ```runtime error: store to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment [solution.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>```

Comment: @Денис Мороз It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.  For example why do firstListColSize and secondListColSize  have pointer types?! Moreover it seems they are even not used within the function. Could you provide an example of source data and the expected result data?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  Indeed, I do not use firstColSize and secondColSize in the function, because I do not see the need for it, and on account of the fact that they are passed as pointers, I noticed that on leetcode they often pass this way, because sometimes there are different numbers of columns.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating space for `res` after the *for* loop. When the program enters the *for* loop, the memory for `res` hasn't been allocated.

The reason you put the allocation after the loop is probably that you don't know exactly the value of `a` before the loop. If memory cost is not a priority, you can allocate a large number of memory beforehand, and free the extra before the function returns. If the program is to run in a memory-sensitive environment, you can implement a data structure similar to C++'s `vector`, i.e. allocate a small piece of memory, and expand the array when free slots run low.

Comment: I tried doing it before my cycle ( int **res = malloc(sizeof(int) * (10 * 2)); )but i get another error (runtime error: store to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebebebe for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment [solution.c]
0xbebebebebebebebe: note: pointer points here
<memory cannot be printed>) in the same line

Comment: @ДенисМороз 10 is much too small here. I'm guessing you're trying to solve a question on LeetCode. The numbeer of intersections in their test cases should be way larger than 10. You should look for clues on this in the question's description. In this case try `malloc(sizeof(int) * (1000 * 2))`.